# `Invalid mapping` error trying to use babel require hook and polyfill with react jsx transpile

Tags: source-maps, reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to use babel for both ES6 and JSX transpilation for mocha tests.

Suppose we have `test.jsx` like this:

```
var React = require("react");
React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (<div>Hello World</div>);
  }
});
```

Running `babel test.jsx` gives us valid transformed code. No problem.

I would expect that if I create a `test.js` file like this:

```
require("babel/register");
require("./test.jsx");
```

And then run `node test.js`, it would transpile my jsx for me in line, but instead I get an error:

```
c:\Users\user\dev\app\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\babel\t
ransformation\file\index.js:628
      throw err;
            ^
Error: c:/Users/user/dev/app/test.jsx: Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line"
:6,"column":11},"source":"c:/Users/user/dev/app/test.jsx","name":null}
    at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (c:/Users/user/dev/app/node_modules\babel\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map\source-map-
generator.js:275:15)
    at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (c:/Users/user/dev/app/
node_modules\babel\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map\source-map-generator.j
s:105:14)
    at SourceMap.mark (c:/Users/user/dev/app/node_modules\babel\node_modules
\babel-core\lib\babel\generation\source-map.js:65:9)
    at CodeGenerator.print (c:/Users/user/dev/app/node_modules\babel\node_mo
dules\babel-core\lib\babel\generation\index.js:236:16)
    at NodePrinter.plain (c:/Users/user/dev/app/node_modules\babel\node_modu
les\babel-core\lib\babel\generation\node\printer.js:16:27)
    at CodeGenerator.ReturnStatement (c:/Users/user/dev/app/node_modules\bab
el\node_modules\babel-core\lib\babel\generation\generators\statements.js:120:13)

    at CodeGenerator.print c:/Users/user/dev/app/node_modules\babel\node_mo
dules\babel-core\lib\babel\generation\index.js:238:22)
    at NodePrinter.plain (c:/Users/user/dev/app/node_modules\babel\node_modu
les\babel-core\lib\babel\generation\node\printer.js:16:27)
    at CodeGenerator.printJoin (c:/Users/user/dev/app/node_modules\babel\nod
e_modules\babel-core\lib\babel\generation\index.js:286:13)
    at NodePrinter.sequence (c:/Users/user/dev/app/node_modules\babel\node_m
odul

es\babel-core\lib\babel\generation\node\printer.js:23:27)
```

According to the docs, it looks like this should work. Am I missing something obvious, or should I report this as a bug in babel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [a bug in acorn-jsx](https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/94), the JSX parser that Babel uses. The recommended fix would be:

```
rm -rf node_modules/babel && npm install
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that I already cleared my node_modules folder, and grabbed the latest version of babel (5.6.3). I tried again just now, but things are unchanged.

Comment: It definitely felt like a downstream-dependency issue to me, though, so glad to see others reporting similar errors. It looks like acorn@2.0.0 should fix the problem, but babel is still pulling in 1.2.2 on my box? Perhaps babel needs to pin to acorn@2.0.0?

Comment: Can you look at the version you have in `node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/acorn-jsx/package.json`? It should be `1.0.3`. Do you happen to have an NPM registry cache somewhere?

Comment: I've got acorn-jsx@1.1.0 in that folder. `npm ls` confirms that.

Comment: And yes, I'm behind a caching npm mirror.

Comment: `1.1.0` was unpublished from `npm` because it contains the bug that is triggering this. Your cache must not have deleted it yet. You could also try `npm cache clean` to make sure it's not in your local cache.

Comment: I removed `acorn` and `acorn-jsx` from our mirror, and everything works again. I should have thought to look at those dependency versions, but I hadn't had this problem before. Now I know what to look for. Good catch! Thanks for your help.